# Windows 10 net usage

Tags: windows-10, internet, firewall

How to stop Windows 10 apps like money, news from accessing internet?

I have Norton Security, so I blocked internet to these apps through Norton Firewall page. Then if I open these apps, itsays "no internet connection", but it's getting updates in the background, it's showing new updated notification time to time, when I click the notification, it opens the app but shows no net connection.

So how to completely block the net usage, even that background notification update usage?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.howtogeek.com/227093/how-to-block-an-application-from-accessing-the-internet-with-windows-firewall/

Comment: as I said already; news,weather,money,cortana are already blocked in firewall. and is showing no net connection when I open them. but its getting new datas in background, new notifications were coming in intervals.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the Store application to stop automatic updates.
If you want to manually update them, you can select which modern UI apps to update.

Edit: To block livetile updates, you could try blocking Windows Explorer from accessing the internet.

Comment: I am not talking about the app's update. Im talking about its content update.   like new news in 'news' app new sharemarket data in 'money' app

Comment: you could turn off live tile updates? It is not blocking the traffic, but the apps will no longer request updates.
Also found this here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/live-tiles-not-working-windows-10/5a8e2ced-06a6-4b98-bfd4-da4896c9b6f9?page=3&auth=1
It says the live tile updates are via "Windows Explorer traffic over http", which is why they can still access the internet. This is why the tiles still get updates, but when you open the app, it says "No internet connection" because it is not the same traffic.

Comment: Oh so thats y its getting updated in background. So how to prevent that? blocking windows explorer from accessing internet or blocking any perticular IP address??

Comment: I think if you blocked windows explorer from accessing the internet, it may block other functionality.
But if you look at what ips are being used, you could try just blocking windows explorer from accessing those IPs. I do not know what the ips are for each service though.